# Confusion regrading Stokes' and Gauss Divergence Theorem while evaluating $\iint(\nabla \times F)\cdot dS$

Tags: surface-integrals, divergence-operator, stokes-theorem, curl, divergence-theorem

Suppose, $F$ be a smooth vector field. Now, we want to evaluate $\iint(\nabla \times F)\cdot dS$ where $S=\{(x,y,z)|x^2+y^2+z^2=1,z\le0\}$ i.e. $S$ is lower half part of unit sphere.

[image: Lower half part of the unit sphere]

**Now suppose we add the lower part on the $xy$-plane (which is $\{(x,y,z)|x^2+y^2\le1,z=0\}$$=S''$(say)) to S and call it $S'$. Now, $S'$ forms a closed and bounded region in $\Bbb{R}^3$.** 
So,  $\iint(\nabla \times F)\cdot dS'=\iiint\nabla\cdot (\nabla \times F)dV=0$ (by [Gauss Divergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem) and the fact $\nabla\cdot (\nabla \times F)=0$)
Now, since $S\cup S''=S'$, we can write $\iint(\nabla \times F)\cdot dS=\iint(\nabla \times F)\cdot dS'-\iint(\nabla \times F)\cdot dS''=-\iint(\nabla \times F)\cdot dS''$  $\cdots$ (1)
Now recall $S''=\{(x,y,z)|x^2+y^2\le1,z=0\}$, from (1) and by [Stokes' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem), we have $\iint(\nabla \times F)\cdot dS=-\oint_{c} F.dr$ where $c(t)=(\cos t,\sin t), t\in[0,2\pi]$ (since outward normal for $S''$ is $\hat k$ and by right hand rule orientation of the boundary of $''$ will be counter clockwise).
Thus, we finally get $\iint(\nabla \times F)\cdot dS=-\oint_{c} F.dr$  $\cdots$ (2)
Again, if we apply Stokes' Theorem directly in the problem we will get
$\iint(\nabla \times F)\cdot dS=\oint_{c} F.dr$ where $c$ is the boundary parametrized by $c(t)=(\cos t,\sin t), t\in[0,2\pi]$.
Comparing this and (2), we have  $\oint_{c} F.dr=-\oint_{c} F.dr$!!!
Can anybody clear this confussion? Where is the falacy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your closed surface $S'$, as you’ve correctly noticed, is made up of two separate oriented components $S$ and $S''$ which share the same border, but induce on it two opposite orientations: the border of $S''$ is $\partial S''$, the unit circle traversed in the *counterclockwise* sense, the border of $S$ is $\partial S$, the same as $\partial S''$ but traversed in the clockwise sense. As the integrand $\nabla \times F$ is the same on both surface components, Stokes’ theorem ensures that the two contributions cancel out:
$$\iint_{S'} (\nabla \times F)\cdot da = \oint_{\partial S} F \cdot d\ell + \oint_{\partial S''} F \cdot d\ell = \oint_{\partial S} F \cdot d\ell - \oint_{\partial S} F \cdot d\ell = 0. $$
Just like computing the volume integral of the divergence had indicated.

Comment: I think you have missed out the notations, $S''$ is the disc on $xy$-plane, $S'$ is the closed region and $S$ is the given lower half part of the unit sphere. Can you please update your answer?

Comment: Sorry for the mixup. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

When you use Gauss' Theorem, you're measuring outward flux.  On your $S$, this would be downward.  Using the right-hand rule on your curve, you're now orienting the flux upward.  That would change the sign.

Comment: I cannot understand. I have applied Gauss Theorem only on $S'$.

Comment: $S^\prime$ includes $S$.  Gauss's theorem measures outward flux.  That would be downward for the bottom part of $S^\prime.$

Comment: Yes, we want to find the integral taking outward normal to $S$, so outward normal for $S$ will be downward. So, where is the fallacy? Could you please write the expressions?

Comment: If you want downward normal, then you need to parametrize the circle in the opposite direction.

Comment: Ok, I understand.